# How do I use sudo to run multiple commands as another user within a portion of a script?

Tags: shell-script, files, sudo, ksh

I'm trying to run the following:

```
if [! -f .owner ]; then
    creator=$(whoami)
    sudo -u appuser ksh
    echo "$creator" >> .owner
    mkdir test1 test2 test3
    exit
fi
```

However, the file/folders get made by the person that runs the script. Any way to make these get created by appuser?

**Edit**: `sudo -l` returns `(appuser) NOPASSWD: ALL`

Comment: you can just change the owner at the end of the script.

Comment: you could run your script using `sudo` and then use `su` inside your script

Comment: Users running this script won't be super users, the appuser account itself is also not a super user. [Chown isn't available to unprivileged users](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chown).

The purpose for this script is that the appuser creates a whole bunch of files when it first gets ran (hence the need to track the person that called the job). The folder these files are located in have read-only access to their common group.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    id
    touch script-run-user.file

    sudo -u appuser 'ksh' <<EOF
    # add list of cmds to execute
    id
    touch appuser.file 
    EOF
```

**Edit**: Just as an update, check out [Here Documents](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document). EOF = "End Of File", the name is arbitrary.

Comment: This is correct - but this is just a note that the reason this works and the other didn't is that the `>>` means the shell creates the file - and its process is owned by the user invoking the script so files it creates are owned by that user, but here you change users then invoke `touch` - which also creates files owned by the user invoking it.